# Mysql query log is empty after boot

Tags: mysql, logging, mysql5.5

I can't figure out why is general and slow query log empty after computer restart. After restarting the server with systemctl the logs get populated.
After reboot the files are created just empty.

```
$ stat /var/log/mysql/query.log
  File: '/var/log/mysql/query.log'
  Size: 0               Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   regular empty file
Device: 801h/2049d      Inode: 6947352     Links: 1
Access: (0660/-rw-rw----)  Uid: (   89/   mysql)   Gid: (   89/   mysql)
Access: 2016-04-28 05:04:04.530835820 +0200
Modify: 2016-04-28 05:04:04.530835820 +0200
Change: 2016-04-28 05:04:04.530835820 +0200
 Birth: -
$ stat /var/log/mysql/slow.log
  File: '/var/log/mysql/slow.log'
  Size: 0               Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   regular empty file
Device: 801h/2049d      Inode: 6947484     Links: 1
Access: (0660/-rw-rw----)  Uid: (   89/   mysql)   Gid: (   89/   mysql)
Access: 2016-04-28 05:04:04.530835820 +0200
Modify: 2016-04-28 05:04:04.530835820 +0200
Change: 2016-04-28 05:04:04.530835820 +0200
 Birth: -
```

my.cnf:

```
# The MariaDB server
[mysqld]
port    = 3306
socket = /run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
skip-external-locking
key_buffer_size = 16M
max_allowed_packet = 1M
table_open_cache = 64
sort_buffer_size = 512K
net_buffer_length = 8K
read_buffer_size = 256K
read_rnd_buffer_size = 512K
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 8M
character-set-server = utf8

general_log = 1 # log every query
general_log_file = /var/log/mysql/query.log

slow_query_log = 1
long_query_time = 1
```

Systemd unit file:

```
$ cat /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/mysqld.service
[Unit]
Description=MariaDB database server
After=syslog.target

[Service]
User=mysql
Group=mysql

ExecStart=/usr/bin/mysqld --pid-file=/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid 
ExecStartPost=/usr/bin/mysqld-post

Restart=always
PrivateTmp=true

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

After service restart the logs get populated:

```
$ sudo systemctl restart mysqld.service 
$ stat /var/log/mysql/query.log
  File: '/var/log/mysql/query.log'
  Size: 255             Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 801h/2049d      Inode: 6947352     Links: 1
Access: (0660/-rw-rw----)  Uid: (   89/   mysql)   Gid: (   89/   mysql)
Access: 2016-04-28 05:04:04.530835820 +0200
Modify: 2016-04-28 06:50:52.534122763 +0200
Change: 2016-04-28 06:50:52.534122763 +0200
 Birth: -
$ stat /var/log/mysql/slow.log
  File: '/var/log/mysql/slow.log'
  Size: 171             Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 801h/2049d      Inode: 6947484     Links: 1
Access: (0660/-rw-rw----)  Uid: (   89/   mysql)   Gid: (   89/   mysql)
Access: 2016-04-28 05:04:04.530835820 +0200
Modify: 2016-04-28 06:50:51.854122769 +0200
Change: 2016-04-28 06:50:51.854122769 +0200
 Birth: -
```